# android studio - within library project how to reference app resources

Tags: android, android-library

I'd like to expose my application resources to a library project that i have created.  the library is called auth (is a fork of firebase UI) and it is a library module in android studio. i then have my application code to build the app. but there are a few resources i'd like the library to be able to see.  would it be better to just copy the resource into the library ? i think not as its taking up more space that way. How can i exposes just the resources ? the other idea i had was put all the resources into a "common-library" where both application and auth can access it ? but it kinda messes up my clean architecture i think this way.  another thing i could do is make the library depend on application. so there would be a circular dependency.  is that ok, because then not just my resources but code is also exposed?

i've tried passing in drawables as parameters but looking for another solution, perhaps in gradle ?

Comment: Circular dependencies between modules are always problematic. Solutions to avoid them include factoring out common parts, merging modules into one, separating interfaces from implementation, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to do it exactly. I can't imagine any extreme situation where you should use, but If you stick to it, you can do with [Resources.getIdentifier()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

*int getIdentifier (String name, 
                String defType, 
                String defPackage)*

Example :

```
resources.getString(resources.getIdentifier("app_name", "string", "app_package_name"))
```

I've tried it and it works fine but I wouldn't recommend it.

PS : I can totally agree with Henry's comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the resources to the library. If they have the same name Android build will just merge the resources so you won't get duplicates. Mind the priority though, it depends on build order.

Comment: this is the answer i was hoping for. so your saying as long as the resource is the same not (no prefix etc) then when i make a production build only one resource will be allocated, right ?

Comment: Yes, this works if you don't expect your resources to change and don't mind having duplicates in your repo. [Official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources.html#resource_merging) for Android

Answer (score 0):

i just figured a even clever way to do all this. we can do it from styles.  if i override the same library styles in the application, it will affect the library (as long as we keep the same name). this is kind of enforcing miles_christian answer. here is the basic concept:

in your library declare a style such as:

```
<style name="MyApp.my_library_style">
        <item name="drawableStartCompat">@drawable/fui_ic_phone_white_24dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/mylibrary_logo</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
```

if you want to override the background for example in your applications style declare the exact same stye declaration in your app, and it will be override:

```
<style name="MyApp.my_library_style">
        <item name="drawableStartCompat">@drawable/fui_ic_phone_white_24dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/myapp_logo</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
```